# How to fix 'class name (...) does not match path (...)' error in unity

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a new AAR plugin in Android Studio. It contains only one simple java class:

```
package com.neitron.shareplugin;

public class ShareProvider {
    private static final ShareProvider ourInstance = new ShareProvider();

    public static ShareProvider getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private ShareProvider() {
    }

    public String GetTestMesssage(int num)
    {
        return "Num is: " + num;
    }
}
```

Then I've built it and copied the AAR file to Unity [2018.2.11f1]:

```
../Assets/Plugins/Android/shareplugin-release.aar
```

When I'm trying to build the project in unity it throws an exception:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2018.2.11f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\To 
ols\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.2.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "- 
Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/neitron/shareplugin/R) does not match path 
(com/Neitron/shareplugin/R.class)
...while parsing com/Neitron/shareplugin/R.class

PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/neitron/shareplugin/R) does not match path 
(com/Neitron/shareplugin/R.class)
...while parsing com/Neitron/shareplugin/R.class

Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/neitron/shareplugin/R$attr) does not match path 
(com/Neitron/shareplugin/R$attr.class)
...while parsing com/Neitron/shareplugin/R$attr.class

PARSE ERROR:
class name (com/neitron/shareplugin/R$attr) does not match path 
(com/Neitron/shareplugin/R$attr.class)
...while parsing com/Neitron/shareplugin/R$attr.class
```

And so on(

Is there any hacky trick I've missed. I already tried to clean the build in Android studio, checked all manifest files. There is no com.Neitron.sharepludin paths only com.neitron.shareplugin. Also, I've tried to create a blank plugin and blank test unity project and faced with the same issue.

Comment: Your folder name, `Neitron` doesn't match your namespace declaration `neitron`. Its case sensitive and has nothing to do with Unity.

Comment: @Draco18s as I said before "There is no com.Neitron.sharepludin paths only com.neitron.shareplugin". Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction. But I've checked a thousand times - folder name is 'neitron'.
[screenshot of the path](https://monosnap.com/file/HcKV7e2igxdrfHKQNtiAQLQxksO49p)

Comment: Well. I've changed the Android Studio module's company name part of the package name

Before:

    `com.neitron.shareplugin`
After:

    `com.neitronnative.shareplugin`
And it works just perfect!
The unity package name is:

    `com.Neitron.ProductName`
My theory that unity and android studio module package names are in the argument and better solution avoid same company names. I could try to change the unity package name to lowercase, but my game is being published already. I'll be glad to hear other ideas!